# Real time data from Ethernet Module to Simulink

Tags: matlab, video-streaming, simulink, ethernet

I have video processing MATLAB codes that I want to feed real time video from ethernet module(Marvell Alaska 88E1510) to PC for these MATLAB codes.

Therefore, I can simulate my code on the real time scenarios. I have searched Simulink and some sources but there is no similar problem. If there is any solution or source, it would be help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate with Simulink in realtime using a UDP packets: [Basic UDP Communication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/examples/basic-udp-communication.html)